# El mejor libro para aprender Python

Tags: python, pdf, epub

¿Cuál es el mejor libro para aprender **Python** y dónde podría descargarlo gratis en formato **pdf** o **epub**?

Comment: Hola @EdgarGalindez, bienvenido a SO. Te recomiendo leer el [Cómo preguntar](https://stackoverflow.com/help) para poder obtener excelentes respuestas de la comunidad; por el momento, tu pregunta no se ajusta a SO en Español.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como "basada principalmente en opiniones".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buscando un poco por internet puedes encontrar varias opciones, y a demás de manera gratuita.
Te recomiendo que mires las opciones que dan en esta página:
http://www.skulltrap.co/2017/04/5-libros-para-aprender-programar-en.html

Espero haberte podido ayudar.

Comment: Gracias @zuninool04, muy interesante y útil el enlace... Saludos!

Comment: Hola zuninool04, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español. Te recomiendo que completes el [tour] y que leas [answer] (y así ganarás una nueva medalla además de aprender cómo funciona el sitio en general).